# Set Cookie Format for Domain

Tags: javascript

I am setting Cookies via Javascript:

```
Example:  document.cookie = "mycookie=false; expires=0; path=/; domain=127.0.0.1";
```

For some reason it's not setting the cookie...is the format wrong or I'm I forgetting something?

Comment: Edit your hosts file and map some URL with a TLD to the address 127.0.0.1 like: 'yoursite.tld   127.0.0.1' and then use that domain instead of 127.0.0.1 and try again.

Comment: Hmm it doesn't seem to be that as I've tried this and I've still got the same problem ... Is the syntax right?

Comment: Yes the syntax seems to be correct.

Comment: Would it make a difference that the code is in a js file called from a wordpress plugin?